# java.lang.ClassCastException: models.Task cannot be cast to models.Task on Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.3

I made a job queue in Play Framework by using Akka actors, I start the actor system from global object. JobManager actor (which is shown below) checks the database every minute and if there is an uncomplete task, it sends a message to Worker actor to process it. Under that you can see my Task model.

```
case class CheckDatabase()

class JobManager extends Actor {

  def receive = { case CheckDatabase() => CheckIt }

  def CheckIt = {

    val allTasks: List[Task] = new Model.Finder(classOf[String], classOf[Task]).all()
    val taskBuffer = new ArrayBuffer[Boolean]
    for(i <- 0 until allTasks.size){ taskBuffer += allTasks.get(i).isRunning }
    if(taskBuffer.forall(taskIsRunning => taskIsRunning == false)){
      val nextTask = nextOntheLine
      if(nextTask != null ){
        val worker = context.system.actorOf(Props[Worker], name = nextTask.id)
        worker ! StartWorking(nextTask)
      } else {
        println("Status: idle...")
      }
    }
  }

  def nextOntheLine: Task = {

    val tasks = new Model.Finder(classOf[String], classOf[Task])
      .where
      .eq("isDone", false)
      .eq("isCancelled", false)
      .eq("isRunning", false)
      .orderBy("uploadDate asc")
      .findList()

    if(tasks.size > 0){
      tasks.get(0)
    } else {
      null
    }
  }
}

@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id
    public String id; 

    public String email; 

    public boolean isDone; 

    public void setIsDone(boolean _isdone){
        isDone = _isdone;
    }

    public boolean isRunning; 

    public void setIsRunning(boolean _isrunning){
        isRunning = _isrunning;
    }

    public boolean isCancelled; 

    public void setIsCancelled(boolean _iscancelled){
        isCancelled = _iscancelled;
    }

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="hh:mm:ss, dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date uploadDate = new Date(); 

}
```

It starts to work perfectly fine, when I send requests it starts the jobs and completes them but during processing of a job (while checking the database with JobManager) I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: models.Task cannot be cast to models.Task` error. As you can see actors are written in Scala but my model is written in Java. Could it be caused by that?

Comment: This is just a guess, but could that be a class-loader issue?

Comment: Could you give some more explanation?

Comment: This is a classical class loader issue.  When you use multiple class loaders, a class file loaded by LoaderA is not the same as the identical class file loaded by LoaderB.  One must take care to only load a given class once, or else be very careful to keep the doppelgangers from meeting each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made another class in Java and rewrote all the methods inside `JobManager` as static methods. Then I imported them to Scala code and problem was solved. It seems like problem was that it was a Java project and models work according to that.